# Как составить правильную конструкцию в Django post_save signal

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

**Имеется:** django 2.2 Python 3.7

**Модели:** Post и кастомная Group связаны через М2М. При добавлении нового поста, пользователь передает slug группы и нужно связать пост с группой по этому слагу. В итоге, при сохранении поста я получаю трейсбэк что у поста нет id (т.к. пост еще не сохранен в БД).

**Замысел такой**: Сначала сохраняем пост в БД, потом через сигнал post_save передаем посту слаг группы.

**Вопрос:** Как правильно это реализовать? Точнее как правильно написать сам сигнал? Я почитал документацию, но так и не разобрался (

---

**Post.model**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='post_author', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Автор')
    title = models.CharField('Название', max_length=255)
    slug = models.CharField('Идентификатор', max_length=255, db_index=True, unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField('Обложка', default='post_image.png', upload_to='posts_images')
    description = models.TextField('Описание')
    content = models.TextField('Пост')

    like = models.ManyToManyField('User', related_name='post_like', blank=True, verbose_name='Лайки')
    dislike = models.ManyToManyField('User', related_name='post_dislike', blank=True, verbose_name='Дизлайки')
    views = models.ManyToManyField('User', related_name='post_views', blank=True, verbose_name='Просмотры')

    publication_date = models.DateTimeField('Дата публикации', auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    beginning_date = models.DateField('Начало события', blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    ending_date = models.DateField('Окончание события', blank=True, null=True, default=None)

    group = models.ManyToManyField('UsersGroup', related_name='post_group', verbose_name='Группа', blank=True)

    is_event = models.BooleanField('Событие', default=False)
    is_news = models.BooleanField('Новость', default=False)
    is_blog_post = models.BooleanField('Статья', default=False)

    active = models.BooleanField('Опубликовано', default=False)
```

**Трэйсбэк:**

```
ValueError at /create_post/gruppa-admina
"<Post: Новый пост | Автор: ЛОГИН: admin, ПОЧТА: admin@mail.com, Аторизация: True | Опубликованно False>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: Где ваш код по обработке `post_save` сигнала?

Comment: @AivanF. А его нет. Точнее не так, я перепробовал уже пачку разных вариаций, по этому и задал вопрос "как правильно составить конструкцию", и подразумевал "как правильно написать этот кусок кода"...